# Visual Studio 15 resource manager 'no items'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to build a window template in a library project, but when i try to add any references there are none to select. I have tried the googling this and the only solution was to allow clr, which did nothing...

Am i doing something wrong here or is this just a bug and i need a clean install?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean Visual Studio 2015 or version "15" preview?

Comment: visual studio 2105